# How do I resolves the Fernet key error in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to encrypt Passwords but the function below

```
def Get_En_PassID():

    Filename = 'Login_Token.bin'
    if os.path.exists(Filename):
        with open(Filename, 'rb') as file_object:
            for line in file_object:
                encryptedpwd = line.decode('utf-8')
                key = encryptedpwd
                print(key)
            #return encryptedpwd
       
        
    else:
        PW = "encrypted message"
        cipher_suite = Fernet(Fernet.generate_key())
        #ciphered_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(bytes(PW,'utf-8'))   #required to be bytes
        ciphered_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(PW.encode('utf-8'))   #required to be bytes
        with open(Filename, 'wb') as file_object:  file_object.write(ciphered_text)
        key = ciphered_text    
        #return ciphered_text

        
    f = Fernet(key)
    p = f.decrypt(key)
    

    print(p)
```

only returning `ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.`
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I've seen a different question with similar problem and I've tried it but it's still giving this error

the token that's in the file : `gAAAAABfpT0o0lcFJnvTUFmPvwEnrkX7-PK2Bs4t---QDK...b7XdJEr40nJnFAfNM=`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python decode fernet key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917837/python-decode-fernet-key)

Comment: that's what i tried